# Custom insert / delete animations in a modern UICollectionView

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

How to apply custom insert / delete animation for collection view cells when using `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` with `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`?

Previously I did it by subclassing `UICollectionViewLayout` and overriding `initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItem` and `finalLayoutAttributesForDisappearingItem`, but with this new stuff whenever snapshot is applied via diffable data source I only get default "fade" animation for any changes (even though I still override these methods).

Comment: I just solved an issue I encountered with UICollectionView animations, but I'm not sure if the solution might apply to your scenario or not. Do you have any updates on this issue, or would you be able to share any of the code for your layout object or delegate?